# How to cut from string some number in SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem witch cut some text (number) in oracle

I must take only number withn't first '0' before first number'1-9' but in this what I must take are also '0' that I need '0000**1204**'

example '0000**7645**', '000**12305**', '000000**78**' and '0000**1204**00000**123**' or '0000**1234**00000**123**000**40678**'

len from sequence number is always this same 8 or 16 or 24 etc and from each 8 I must remove first seqence with '0' and take separate number

could some one help me?

Comment: Please include the output from `0000120400000123`.  It is not clear (at least to me) exactly what you want here.

Comment: And what about `00000010` - 1 or 10? Or `0000001000000100` - 11, or 10100, or 10 and 100 as two values? You sort of said they should be treated as blocks of 8 digits with leading zeros removed from each block - which would imply you want to get multiple values back from the longer string, and preserve trailing zeros in each one? Please give the actual expected result from each of your examples.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen from  0000120400000123 i need 1204 to first column and 123 in next column etc

Comment: @AlexPoole from 00000010 i need 10 and from 0000001000000100 i need 10 to put in first column and 100 to put in next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments you want the original text to be split into multiple values, and then to have each of those stripped of leading zeros. You referred to multiple columns, which is OK but you have to know how many you could have - i.e. to know the maximum length the original string can be.

As an example where the maximum length is 24 you could split with:

```
select
  regexp_substr(text, '\d{8}', 1, 1) as chunk1,
  regexp_substr(text, '\d{8}', 1, 2) as chunk2,
  regexp_substr(text, '\d{8}', 1, 3) as chunk3
...
```

and then either just remove leading zeros to leave as strings:

```
select
  ltrim(regexp_substr(text, '\d{8}', 1, 1), '0') as str1,
  ltrim(regexp_substr(text, '\d{8}', 1, 2), '0') as str2,
  ltrim(regexp_substr(text, '\d{8}', 1, 3), '0') as str3
```

or convert to numbers:

```
select,
  to_number(regexp_substr(text, '\d{8}', 1, 1)) as num1,
  to_number(regexp_substr(text, '\d{8}', 1, 2)) as num2,
  to_number(regexp_substr(text, '\d{8}', 1, 3)) as num3
```

In each case, to handle a longer string you would need to add more column expressions, incrementing the `occurrence` number (and column name).

With your sample data put into a table `t`:

```
select text,
  to_number(regexp_substr(text, '\d{8}', 1, 1)) as num1,
  to_number(regexp_substr(text, '\d{8}', 1, 2)) as num2,
  to_number(regexp_substr(text, '\d{8}', 1, 3)) as num3
from t
```

| TEXT | NUM1 | NUM2 | NUM3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00001204 | 1204 |  |  |
| 00007645 | 7645 |  |  |
| 00012305 | 12305 |  |  |
| 00000078 | 78 |  |  |
| 0000120400000123 | 1204 | 123 |  |
| 000012340000012300040678 | 1234 | 123 | 40678 |
| 00000010 | 10 |  |  |
| 0000001000000100 | 10 | 100 |  |

If you wanted one *row* per value you could use a hierarchical query or recursive subquery factoring:

```
with rcte (text, chunk_num, chunk, remainder) as (
  select text, 1, substr(text, 1, 8), substr(text, 9)
  from t
  union all
  select text, chunk_num + 1, substr(remainder, 1, 8), substr(remainder, 9)
  from rcte
  where remainder is not null
)
select text, chunk_num, chunk, ltrim(chunk, '0') as str, to_number(chunk) as num
from rcte
order by text, chunk_num
```

| TEXT | CHUNK_NUM | CHUNK | STR | NUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00000010 | 1 | 00000010 | 10 | 10 |
| 0000001000000100 | 1 | 00000010 | 10 | 10 |
| 0000001000000100 | 2 | 00000100 | 100 | 100 |
| 00000078 | 1 | 00000078 | 78 | 78 |
| 00001204 | 1 | 00001204 | 1204 | 1204 |
| 0000120400000123 | 1 | 00001204 | 1204 | 1204 |
| 0000120400000123 | 2 | 00000123 | 123 | 123 |
| 000012340000012300040678 | 1 | 00001234 | 1234 | 1234 |
| 000012340000012300040678 | 2 | 00000123 | 123 | 123 |
| 000012340000012300040678 | 3 | 00040678 | 40678 | 40678 |
| 00007645 | 1 | 00007645 | 7645 | 7645 |
| 00012305 | 1 | 00012305 | 12305 | 12305 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=278ab4316ad20c4df2c3ab6f53731c80)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`REGEXP_REPLACE()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/REGEXP_REPLACE.html#GUID-EA80A33C-441A-4692-A959-273B5A224490) function with **`'[^1-9]'`** pattern such as

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(col,'[^1-9]')
  FROM t -- your table
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `LTRIM`:

```sql
SELECT LTRIM(seq_num, '0')
FROM yourTable;
```

Or, use `REGEXP_REPLACE`:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(seq_num, '^0+', '')
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Hi Tim, `LTRIM` won't work in this case as you already know.